# Use .Net Core Dependency Injection with test project

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to configure EntityFramework for integration tests in an MSTest Project, normally I might configure my project through my startup like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

    var defaultConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

    services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<AstootContext>(options => 
                options.UseSqlServer(defaultConnectionString))
        .AddDbContext<PublicAstootContext>(options => 
                options.UseSqlServer(defaultConnectionString));
    //...
}
```

My testing project looks like so:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1 : ServiceTestBase
{
    string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                      AttachDbFilename=C:\source\Astoot\RestEzCore.Tests\TestDB\NORTHWND.MDF;
                      Integrated Security=True;
                      Connect Timeout=30;
                      User Instance=True";

    [TestInitialize]
    public void RegisterTestModules
    {

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
    }
}
```

How can I reuse the same dependency injection my webapi project uses and so configure my tests in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you should have `MyWebApp` that contains `MyWebApp.Startup` and `MyWebApp.appsettings.json`, the startup class configures everything (it probably uses the json config file).

Now in `MyWebApp.Test`(which should reference `MyWebApp`), create `MyWebApp.Test.Startup` that inherits from `MyWebApp.Startup` if you need to override something, and `MyWebApp.Test.appsettings.json` (to use different configs e.g. ConnectionString), then you can create your test server like this:

```
var builder = WebHost
    .CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()  //the Startup can be MyWebApp.Startup if you have nothing to customize
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(b => b.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json"));

var server = new TestServer(builder);
var client = server.CreateClient();
//send requests via client
```

Comment: it’s there a way I can just use the start up without having to pull in the whole project, ideally I just want to use the servicecollection to grab out what I need for each test

Comment: Or should I just create a new web api project setup my services collection and then add maters nugets

Comment: @johnny5 The startup class uses other types defined in the project, it can't work without them.

Comment: Thanks, I see so either I have to move so I either have to move a bunch of packages, or reference the project